# Web Api Repository/ValueController problem

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

I develop web application. I started from Web Api with Entity Framework. I want realize CRUD function. 
Read function works fine
But problem with Create, Update, Delete, could you check it and tell me, what I do wrong?

I attach 2 blocks of code, I don't know how I can realize 1st repository (Mistake in C,U,D - function) in controller.

I don't have enough experience with web api, could you tell me, how I need setting Repository(only for realize create, delete, update) file and after realize it in Value Controller

I need your advice about create, update, delete - function
Customer Repos

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class CustomerRepository
    {
        public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();
            return dev.Customers;
        }

        public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers(int id)
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();
            return dev.Customers.Where(c=>c.Id==id).Select(e=>e);
        }

        public IQueryable<Customer> DeleteCustomer(int id)
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();
            var cus = dev.Customers.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            dev.Entry(cus).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
            dev.SaveChanges();
            return cus;
        }

        }
        public IQueryable<Customer> CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();
            dev.Customers.Add(new Customer()
             {
                 Id = customer.Id,
                Name = customer.Name
            });
            dev.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();

        }

        public IQueryable<Customer> UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            DevelopersEntities dev = new DevelopersEntities();
            var cus = dev.Customers.Where(s => s.Id == customer.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            cus.Id = customer.Id;
            cus.Name = customer.Name;
            dev.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Values Controller

```
using DevelopersWeb.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebAPI;

namespace DevelopersWeb.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        ModelFactory _modelFactory;

        public ValuesController()
        {
            _modelFactory = new ModelFactory();
        }
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> Get()
        {
            CustomerRepository cr = new CustomerRepository();
            return cr.GetAllCustomers().ToList().Select(c=> _modelFactory.Create(c));
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "xxx";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody] CustomerModel customerModel)
        {
            CustomerRepository cr = new CustomerRepository();
            cr.CreateCusomer(customer);

            return Ok();
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add description of your problem in the post , to be more helpfull

Comment: I done it. I have repository for 4 methods(get, update, insert, delete). I have problem with all methods (without get). After that I need implement it in Value Controller. I don't know, how I can do it

Comment: Why you returning the collection of customers in CustomerRepository for C, U, D. While you accessing the api of create, is it inserting in DB. If yes means, you can return 200 response and if not, you can return 500. Better, you can keep HttpResponseMessage for these C, U, D methods.

Comment: Why is it better?